# Can I use diastatic malt in applications which call for non-diastatic?

Tags: substitutions, malt

I am interested in a few different applications of barley malt some of which classically would use diastatic malt and some use non diastatic malt. 
I’d rather just purchase one malt for everything. Assuming I can find a diastatic malt powder without any added flours is there any reason I wouldn’t/couldn’t use it in a traditionally non diastatic scenario (such as a malted milkshake)? Many sites claim that diastatic is used for yeast growth, not for flavor but if it’s not diluted with added flours to the powder I don’t see why it couldn’t be.

Answer (score 3):

[diastatic malt powder](http://www.nyx.net/~dgreenw/whatisdiastaticmalt.html) is milled malt that hasn't been heated to deactivate the enzymes.  To deactivate it to use as non-diastatic malt, heat to 130F/55C

Answer (score 1):

the question isnt 'how do i convert diastatic malt to non-diastatic malt?'

the question is whether it's ok to use diastatic malt powder in lieu of non-diastatic malt powder, for example, in a milkshake

diastatic malt powder contains a family of polysaccharide-degrading enzymes, including amylase. these enzymes break down starches and some disaccharides such as sucrose and maltose, into simple sugars digestible by yeast. your body produces amylase in saliva. the amylase acts quickly in the mouth and esophagus and is then destroyed by stomach acid

in non-diastatic malt these enzymes have been destroyed by treatment with heat

i do not know whether it's ok to ingest large amounts of uncooked, non-diastatic malt, or large amounts of the enzymes it contains, but i don't find published evidence that it's harmful